# Can I create a class that subclasses from Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, class, inheritance, swift2

I am fiddling around with making a cocoapod, and I am trying to make a class that sub-classes from type `Array`.

The reason I wan it to sub-class from `Array`, is because `Array` and `NSArray` are treated differently in Swift.

I can create a class like this:

```
class Test : NSArray {}
```

But if I try this:

```
class Test : Array {}
```

Or this:

```
class Test : [AnyObject] {}
```

I get an error.

Mostly the reason I want this is so I can use functions like this:

```
let i = myArray.randomObject()
```

Versus this:

```
let i = Test.randomObject(myArray)
```

Any ideas of what I could do (instead maybe)?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? From your example it sounds like you want an extension rather than a subclass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add methods to Array via an extension. Something like:

```
extension Array
{
    func randomObject() -> Element { return self[ Int( arc4random_uniform( UInt32( self.count ) ) ) ] }
}
```

Now you can do `myArray.randomObject()` where *myArray* is of type *Array*

---

Edit: Also, @Addison correctly pointed out that struct types cannot be subclassed in Swift.

Comment: Note that `arc4random_uniform` expects an argument of type `UInt32`, wheras `self.count` returns `Int`. The same holds for the subsequent access of an index in `self`: index expects type `Int` (int case of indexable), whereas `arc4random_uniform` returns type `UIn32`. So you'll need to include some type conversions/initializations in your example above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot subclass `Array` because it is a struct. An `NSArray` however, is an object so you can subclass that. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you may want to conform to the `CollectionType` protocol instead, which both structs and objects can do, as well as enums.

Comment: You cannot easily subclass NSArray since it's a class cluster. When you create an NSArray/NSMutableArray the class of the returned object may be one of several private implementation classes.

Comment: In any case, better to be able to use standard Array/NSArray in your code everywhere and extend it via extensions than to have to use a custom subclass of Array/NSArray everywhere.

Comment: Ok thanks, I never knew that NSArray was a class custer. Yeah I agree that it's better to just use an extension rather than create a new class or subclass one, but I wanted to explain why you can't subclass Array